# Создание необычных форм из div и input

Tags: html, css

Нужно получить что-то этого вида(форма авторизации на сайте)
[image: форма авторизации]
возможно ли такое сделать? подскажите пожалуйста как

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
span {position:relative;}
.login{
  margin-bottom:10px;
  height:20px;
  border:none;
  background: blue;
  padding-right:40px;
  padding-left:10px;
}

.submit{
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius:100px;
  position:absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>
<input type="text" class="login" placeholder="Login"><br/>
<input type="text" class="login" placeholder="Password"> 
<input type="submit" class="submit" value=" ">
</span>
```

Comment: Как быть с бордером у инпутов вокруг кнопки?

Comment: @E_K, `outline: none;`

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, и что мне даст отлючение обводки, если меня интересовало как сделать border(дугой) для инпутов?

Comment: @E_K - можно поковырять этот пример http://jsfiddle.net/5YS68/

Comment: @E_K, не понял коммент значит. Я б "глянул" в сторону svg